# Insert data from Json that has multiple rows into a table in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Is there any way to insert data from Json which data stored in several rows, insert into a regular table
at first I try to use FOR JSON AUTO but it returns NULL

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON((SELECT * FROM JsonOneColumn))
```

Json table is like this

```
| Value                                                           | 
| --------------------------------------------------------------- | 
| {"Fname":"Cake","Fcount":3,"FDate":"2020-02-13","Fregion":"UK"} | 
| {"Fname":"Coca","Fcount":5,"FDate":"2020-02-13","Fregion":"US"} | 
...
```

it should be like this:

```
| Fname | Fcount | FDate    | Fregion |  
| ----- | ------ | -------- | ------- |
| Cake  | 3      |2020-02-13| UK      |
| Coca  | 5      |2020-02-13| US      |
```

Comment: Is `JsonOneColumn` the name of the table where the json data are being stored?

Comment: Yes, that s the name of the table that Json stored in my DB

Comment: Is `JSON` stored as `VARCHAR`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your JSON data is stored in a way similar to the [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/store-json-documents-in-sql-tables?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
CREATE TABLE Logs (
    _id bigint primary key identity,
    log nvarchar(max)
);

ALTER TABLE Logs
    ADD CONSTRAINT [Log record should be formatted as JSON]
                   CHECK (ISJSON(log)=1)
                   
INSERT INTO Logs
VALUES
('{"Fname":"Cake","Fcount":3,"FDate":"2020-02-13","Fregion":"UK"}'),
('{"Fname":"Coca","Fcount":5,"FDate":"2020-02-13","Fregion":"US"}')
```

you can query the data like this:

```
SELECT 
  JSON_VALUE(log, '$.Fname') AS Fname
  , CAST(JSON_VALUE(log, '$.Fcount') AS INT) AS Fcount
  , CAST(JSON_VALUE(log, '$.FDate') AS DATETIME) AS FDate
  , JSON_VALUE(log, '$.Fregion') AS Fregion
FROM Logs
```

Output:

| Fname | Fcount | FDate | Fregion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cake | 3 | 2020-02-13T00:00:00Z | UK |
| Coca | 5 | 2020-02-13T00:00:00Z | US |

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f4b28/4)

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be my answer:

```
CREATE VIEW OneColumnIntoView
AS  
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON((SELECT CONCAT('[',(STRING_AGG(VALUE,',')),']') AS JC FROM OneColumnJsonFood))

WITH (Fname NVARCHAR(50),
Fcount INT,
Datetype NVARCHAR(4000),
Fregion NVARCHAR(50)) AS WithJson
```

Comment: Hi @sara moradi : this post isn't an answer, you should add this answer in your question for your tried. I voted  your question for give good feedback but you should read how to answer questions in help center. (delete this answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

you need use `PK table` and here this name is `@id` you can choose another.
i don't know about your data types

```
---"Fname":"Cake","Fcount":3,"FDate":"2020-02-13","Fregion":"UK"

SET NOCOUNT ON;  
  
DECLARE @id INT
Declare @table table (Fname nvarchar(50), Fcount int,FDate date,Fregion varchar(10))  
  
DECLARE CR CURSOR FOR   
SELECT [Value] FROM JsonOneColumn 
  
OPEN CR  
  
FETCH NEXT FROM CR   
INTO @id
  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    Declare @test nvarchar(500) = (SELECT [Value] FROM JsonOneColumn where id = @id)
    
    Insert into @table (Fname, Fcount,FDate,Fregion)
    Select Fname, Fcount,FDate,Fregion
    From OpenJSON (@test) With ( Fname   nvarchar(50)   '$.Fname'
                                ,Fcount  int            '$.Fcount'
                                ,FDate   date           '$.FDate'
                                ,Fregion varchar(10))   '$.Fregion')
  
 
        -- Get the next id.  
    FETCH NEXT FROM CR   
    INTO @id  
END   
CLOSE CR;  
DEALLOCATE CR;  

-- Just for check out put
Select * From @table
```